# How can I increase the friction on the surface of PVC pipe?

Tags: finishing, cpvc, rubber, spray-paint

So, I have sort of an odd question - I need a coating (or something) that will increase the friction on a CPVC pipe as much as possible.

Specifically, I rigged some CPVC pipe to mount a light from my bicycle rack (I am a commuter.)

However, the PVC pipe is apparently not a standard size of bicycle tubing, and even as tight as I can get it the light tends to slide around a bit.

Would some sort of rubberized coating work?

(I suppose I could put some inntertube on there, but I suspect stretching it tightly reduces the friction if provides.)

Answer (score 1):

Most bike clamps come with rubber « inserts » for exactly that reason - inner tube cut to fit will work, but consider roughening the pipe surface with glass paper.

Answer (score 0):

Use rubber cement to glue a strip of innertube to the PVC, or wrap the pipe with a single layer of duct tape.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get better suggestions at [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), since this is a *bike* improvement project not a *home* improvement project, but...

Wrapping some inner tube, duct tape, or just about anything else around it should work just fine. I doubt you'd see a significant reduction in friction from stretching the rubber, but what you're really after is making the thing the clamp goes around thick enough that the clamp can apply proper squeezing pressure. You're not really worried about the friction level. If you'd gone up a size in your choice of piping, you'd probably be able to get the light's clamp to tighten down and hold just fine on the exact same material.